# Symfony3 - MISD Phone Number Bundle format

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

Is it possible to set the format returned by the entity containing a phone number property when using [MISD Phone-Number-Bundle](https://github.com/misd-service-development/phone-number-bundle)? For example I have a property $phoneNumber

When I call `$this->getPhoneNumber()` it returns the string formatted:

`Country Code: 1 National Number: ########## Country Code Source:`
but I want it in the format (or similar):
`1 (###) ###-####`

The reason I want to change this is because in that entity I am implementing the __toString() method and want the string returned to be a combination of 2 properties one being the "nickName" and other being the phone number in this type of format or similar `NickName - 1 (###) ###-####` The purpose of this is to display them in a drop down form element setup in a form type I created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my own problem... My `__toString()` method looks like this and seems to do what I want.

```
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil;
//...
public function __toString()
{
    $phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
    $number = $phoneNumberUtil->format($this->phoneNumber, \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL);     

    return $this->nickName . " - " . $number;
}
```

Anyone see any issues or better ways to do this?

Comment: Depends - if this is purely for display purposes you might want to write a Twig filter that allows you to specify whatever format you want.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: In that case what you are doing is fine since that format will appear in the drop-down box.  You have a few other options, like making the above code a static function in your entity that you could call with any phone number, and then your `__toString()` method would call that...so like `public function __toString() { return MyEntity::getFormattedPhoneNumber($this->phoneNumber()); }`.  The benefit there is you could reuse the function anywhere with any phone number.  However, that's not necessary if you only need it in the one place, in which case what you are doing is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Phone number is instance of `libphonenumber\PhoneNumber`. This class has `__toString` method, which returns not formated debug information about object's properties

- https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php/blob/master/src/PhoneNumber.php

I have formated phone number with `temlate` option with SonataAdminBundle:

```
$listMapper
    ->add('phoneNumber', PhoneNumberType::class, [
        'template' => ':CRUD:phoneNumber_list_field.html.twig'
    ]);
```

Template `:CRUD:phoneNumber_list_field.html.twig` contents:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    {% if object.phoneNumber is null %}
        -
    {% else %}
        {{ object.phoneNumber|phone_number_format(2) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here argument `2` for twig filter is `\libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL`

- https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php/blob/master/src/PhoneNumberFormat.php

Comment: @SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_list_field.html.twig instead